# How can I monitor website from mobile and get instant notification via email or sms when content changes in website?

Tags: python, bash, mobile

I am monitoring a website from desktop which needs to be refreshed every 15 minutes and alert us via notification or email when any content in the website changes. Currently, I am using web monitor which is solving my problem but I need the same thing in mobile as well where I can monitor the website continuously and get notified via sms or email when content changes ?

Desktop web monitor is cool application which is instantly giving me notification in desktop and alerting me but when I am away from desktop, I am unable to monitor the website continuously from mobile as I don't know what can we do for mobile notification ?

I am trying to write a batch script or python script but do not have the idea where to begin from

Comment: No, it's simple plain SLA (ticket monitoring ) website where the  row count changes if any ticket arrives in bucke. I just need to monitor that row count continuously from mobile and want a notification instantly when the row count changes.

Comment: Your question is too broad, why is it tagged with python and bash? Does the website have an api? What have you tried/researched?

Comment: Hello. Well I hope you understood my query. Currently I am using a web monitor (chrome extension ) which is giving me notification(sound ) when any ticket arrives and it also gave notifications on my mobile (email ) but since it was a free trial, it stopped giving notification on mobile but desktop notification is free for life time. I need the same thing in mobile as well where some software monitor in mobile (scenario when I am away from desktop ) and notifies me when a change happens in website. I thought  of writing a batch script or python script but a bit clueless

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most generic solution would be to download the webpage and see if it has changed(Not very efficient though)

Simply done with Python3:

```
import requests
import time
import smtplib
_Webpage = 'http://example.org'
_Wait_Time = 60 * 15 #time in seconds
old = requests.get(_Webpage)
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(_Wait_Time)
        new = requests.get(_Webpage)
        if(new.content != old.content):
            print('Change detected at: ' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime()))
            old = new
            #save in file?
            '''with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write('Change detected at: ' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime()))
            '''
            #email? (gmail- requires that you allow third party access to the account first)
            '''
            server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
            server.login("username", "password")
            server.sendmail(
            "from@address.com", 
            "to@address.com", 
            "Change detected at: " + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime()))
            server.quit()
            '''
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n' + 'Exiting..')
```

There are a lot of other methods to do it more efficiently (like using the info provided by the webpage's [last modified header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29)) but that depends on the specific webpage. Perhaps you should provide more info on that matter.

Comment: Hey, thanks  for the info. What more information you need ?

Comment: The domain you're trying to access

Comment: I wish I could you have given you the link but it's an internal confidential link which i  cannot share.

Comment: No problem, just run ```curl -I webpage.com``` in a Linux terminal and see if the output contains any "Last-Modified" headers.